# Cron running script to check line for a comment

Tags: scripting, cron

WE are running plesk on Centos 7 and need to check this config file every 5 minutes to make sure that line x is commented out as plesk keeps un commenting it.
We would run this under cron every 5 minutes...

the file path is 
/etc/proftpd.d/50-plesk.conf

the line we wish to make sure is always commented is...

```
MasqueradeAddress 37.***.4***.60

-----------------------------------
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

# Global section
<Global>
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
TLSEngine on
TLSRequired off
</IfModule>
</Global>
# Global section
<VirtualHost 10.***.***.195>
#MasqueradeAddress 37.***.4***.60
```

Comment: You should find out why plesk keeps adding the line and fix that.

Comment: If you discover the line uncommented, would you also have to restart any services that might now be running “incorrectly”?

Comment: Here is a possible answer about searching and replacing things inside a file, but as @RalfFriedl suggested you should find what is doing this in the first place. https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Comment: Thanks, Plesk support say that there is no way around this and this is the only way.....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a cron job, as a short time measure, tell the OS to write protect that file.

Do:

```
sudo chattr +i  /etc/proftpd.d/50-plesk.conf
```

Obviously, as the comments rightfully tell you, the duty of Plesk Support would be to tell you how to solve that, or give you a software fix.